# Gaining access to mysql given physical access to the machine

Tags: mysql

I own a machine running third party software. I input data into this software and it stores that data into its own mysql database. **I'd like query the mysql database directly, but I don't know the credentials** that the application is using.

**I have read and write access for all files in the machine**, including the files in the mysql data directory. Theoretically, I should be able to read the data directly from these files (.ibd and .frm files). But practically, I don't know where to start. I'm thinking that these data files are somewhat readable since encrypting them would destroy their index-ability.

Is this feasible? Or would I have to reverse engineer the data file format in order to read it?

Or even better - is there some config file that I can change which would implicitly trust all local connections similar to postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the mysql files directly, but even if they're now encrypted, the columns names might be *weird* and you could have to spend some time reading them.

Another point could be looking for config files from that software, that could have the login/password (very very low probability, but who knows?)

And the best would be:

1. make a backup of the mysql files
2. in another mysql instalation / computer (to not break your software), follow the [reset mysql password guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing it via the command line on the local machine:

```
shell> mysql db_name
```

(from [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html))

From here, you can create yourself an account if you need to connect from other client software.

Or have you already tried that?

Answer (score 1):

If you have root access to the machine that MySQL is running on, then you can reset the MySQL root password by following the procedure at: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/recover-mysql-root-password.html.  Once you've reset the root password, you can then login to MySQL as the root MySQL user, and access any of the databases, and query them.  The only caveat to keep in mind is that changing the MySQL root password could potentially prevent your application from accessing the MySQL database, but that would be surprising as the application should be designed to connect to the database using a MySQL user account (with limited privileges) other than the root MySQL user.

Comment: Please prefer links to the [original source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html).